# Firebase not loading credentials in Java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, google-signin

I am using Firebase to handle the authentication in a Java web application, with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. I enabled Google sign in only.

On the front-end I managed to make Firebase work correctly and authenticate the user. So the front-end is fine.

When it comes to validating the token in the back-end, I am trying to use Firebase Admin SDK as recommended in the documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

I am using the latest version to date.

```
compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.1.1')
```

I am initialising Firebase in the back-end, to then verify the Google token I got in the front-end using Javascript, and that I am passing to the back-end in a POST request.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

The problem is that Firebase doesn't seem to load the credentials from the credentials file that you have to download for you application (how to get the credentials file is documented in the first link above, and it is just a JSON file with things like type, project_id, private_key and so on).

```
try (FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(credentialsFilePath)) {
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
      .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
      .setDatabaseUrl(databaseURL)
      .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("Firebase credentials file not found");
    throw e;
}
```

It is definitely finding the file, but when I inspect the credentials they have null values, and when I try to verify the token I get this exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: projectId must be set
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:122)
at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FirebaseTokenVerifier.<init>(FirebaseTokenVerifier.java:50)
at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FirebaseTokenVerifier$Builder.build(FirebaseTokenVerifier.java:212)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$2.then(FirebaseAuth.java:156)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$2.then(FirebaseAuth.java:152)
at com.google.firebase.tasks.ContinueWithCompletionListener$1.run(ContinueWithCompletionListener.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have read through the documentation and looked at the examples in their GitHub repository but they don't seem to have a full working example of Firebase using Java in a web application.

So the question is, how can I make it work? how is people using Firebase in this context?

Thanks.

P.S. 1: I am not running the application in Google Cloud Platform, so I cannot use FirebaseCredentials.applicationDefault() to let Google automatically load the credentials.

P.S. 2: I had to exclude module: 'guava-jdk5' from the Firebase dependency because I am also using spring-data-elasticsearch and it was not working because of a dependency clash. But I still have guava:18.0 in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Verify your downloaded key file is latest or not, try downloading it again if you are not sure, verify database url is updated with your projectId or not.

Try copying your file to any resources dir to copy it into any of your module jars or WEB-INF/classes by build then use class.getResourceAsStream()

```
private void initFireBaseServiceAccount() {
        InputStream serviceAccount =
                this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/PROJECTID-firebase-adminsdk-service-account.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://PROJECTID.firebaseio.com")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    }
```

Keeping cred file in classpath and loading it with class.getResourceAsStream() and initializing FirebaseApp worked for my app.

Note: I am newbie to firebase and tested this by starting dev server in my local machine.